# Bootstrap modal overflowing my table row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

See http://jsfiddle.net/9sjRh/

I have table in a modal but it is overflowing. I have playing css tricks with it such as changing the width of the modal or changing the margins. None of these seems to have worked. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML

```
<div id="classModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1"
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="classInfo" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
              ×
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="classModalLabel">
              Class Info
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>CLN</td>
                  <td>Last Updated Date</td>
                  <td>Class Name</td>
                  <td># Tests</td>
                  <td>Test Coverage (Instruction)</td>
                  <td>Test Coverage (Complexity)</td>
                  <td>Complex Covered</td>
                  <td>Complex Total</td>
                  <td>Category</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
              Close
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$('#classModal').modal('show')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override the style 8px to 5px or less

```
 .table > thead > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td, .table > tbody > tr > td, .table > tfoot > tr > td {

        padding: 5px !important; // currently 8px
    }
```

the syle is currently in bootstrap.min.css you may add the following style in your own css class.

Comment: Two things on this... You should hardly ever (nay never) have to use `!important` as that has severe implications.  Also, when in doubt, scroll.

Answer (score 18):

I am not sure if the issue is resolved or not but my solution is :

Append the below written CSS tag into your fiddle and get the thing done.

```
.modal-body {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

You can find my JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamakshay04/sh26m80o/2/).

Answer (score 6):

I know its too late but this is what worked for me

Wrapped the table inside a div and added overflow:auto as a style

```
<div style="overflow: auto">
       <table class="table table-hover">

            <thead>
                <tr >
                   <th id="th1">Header 1</th>
                   <th id="th2">Header 2</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

             <tbody>

             </tbody>

          </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Table tries it's best to fit the contents within the container, but if your text is too long it will be forced to override the container's width and spread. You can force it to still re-size within the container using `table-layout:fixed` but it will cause undesirable formatting like **[this.](http://jsfiddle.net/TmWP4/1/)**

If you have lengthy headers, I recommend you to follow the vertical header approach which looks like:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <td>Value 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <td>Value 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Have a look at the formatting I made **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/TmWP4/2/)** on your code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of user1707141 works.
But Bootstrap has its specific class for your table : table-responsive

Documentation about this element here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#always-responsive

Answer (score 0):

First thing: you must wrap your table in a `div` with the class `table-responsive`.

My problem was (in Bootstrap 3) that the `div.table-responsive` was inside a `div.container`, I put the `div.table-responsive` outside the `div.container` and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For Overflowing Text you need to add this class

```
td{
white-space : normal;
}
```

bootstrap default class sets it to no-wrap causing the table to overflow when you have long text. This works perfectly